# What are matrix spaces used for in Sage?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sagemath

What are some computations/ calculations in Sagemath which are done better/ more elegantly because of the existence of matrix spaces? Most of the times it seems to me that constructing matrices with `matrix()` would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for the existence of matrix spaces is to be the [parent](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_coercion.html) of matrices. This is especially useful for enabling [conversion and coercion](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_coercion.html#conversion-versus-coercion). In particular, they are used when you call `change_ring()` on a matrix.

So they perform important tasks mainly in the background, as good parents do.

---

They can sometimes be useful on the foreground, as seen in some examples in the [documentation on Matrix Spaces](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/matrix_space.html).

- Random elements:

  ```
  sage: Mat(QQ,2,5).random_element(density=0.5)
  [  2   0   0   0   1]
  [  0   0   0 1/2   0]
  ```
- Basis of the space of matrices:

  ```
  sage: list(Mat(QQ,2).basis())
  [
  [1 0]  [0 1]  [0 0]  [0 0]
  [0 0], [0 0], [1 0], [0 1]
  ]
  ```